# Oracle Dynamic Pivoting

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the below table. I need to create columns based off the column CCL. The values in column CCL are unknown. I'm not sure where to begin here. Any help would be appreciated.

TABLEA

```
ID    CCL    Flag
1     john     x
1     adam     x
1     terry
1     rob      x
2     john     x
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA
```

Output:

```
ID  John  Adam  Terry  Rob
 1    x     x           x
 2    x
```

Comment: Please have a look at this blog post - it should be helpful https://thesqlserverdeveloper.blogspot.com/2018/02/performing-dynamic-pivot.html?view=magazine

Comment: There are essentially three choices here. (1) Don't do it. (2) If you need to do it, and it's only for a final report, then use a reporting front-end that can do the pivoting. That is where "dynamic pivoting" (which is what this is called) belongs, in most cases. (3) If you need to do this because you need the result in further calculations, then be advised that this is an advanced topic. It has to do with dynamic SQL, something that should only be used as a last resort, and it is definitely not for beginners. So, if you are a beginner, don't try it!

Comment: @John Could you provide some expect result?

Comment: @D-Shih added expected output

Comment: Very good article on the subject, with ready-made PL/SQL API for this: https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/.  I have used it and it works in _most_ cases.  E.g., don't try to use it in dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using dynamic sql for a result where the columns are unknown at the time of executing is a bit of a hassle in Oracle compared to certain other RDMBS.

Because the record type for the output is yet unknown, it can't be defined beforehand.

In Oracle 11g, one way is to use a nameless procedure that generates a temporary table with the pivoted result.

Then select the results from that temporary table.

```sql
declare
  v_sqlqry clob;
  v_cols clob;
begin
  -- Generating a string with a list of the unique names
  select listagg(''''||CCL||''' as "'||CCL||'"', ', ') within group (order by CCL)
  into v_cols
  from 
  (
    select distinct CCL
    from tableA
  );

  -- drop the temporary table if it exists
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE tmpPivotTableA';
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN RAISE; END IF;

  -- A dynamic SQL to create a temporary table 
  -- based on the results of the pivot
  v_sqlqry := '
    CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE tmpPivotTableA
    ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT ID, CCL, Flag FROM TableA) src 
    PIVOT (MAX(Flag) FOR (CCL) IN ('||v_cols||')) pvt';

  -- dbms_output.Put_line(v_sqlqry); -- just to check how the sql looks like
  execute immediate v_sqlqry;
  
end;
/

select * from tmpPivotTableA;
```

**Returns:**

```
ID  adam john rob terry
--  ---- ---- --- -----
1   x    x    x
2        x
```

You can find a test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4b19a5307d74c5e01e83f73c99507f30)*

In Oracle 11g, another cool trick (created by [Anton Scheffer](https://technology.amis.nl/author/anton-scheffer/)) to be used can be found in this [blog](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/).  But you'll have to add the pivot function for it.
The source code can be found [in this zip](https://technology.amis.nl/wp-content/uploads/images/antonsPivoting.zip)

After that the SQL can be as simple as this:

```sql
select * from 
table(pivot('SELECT ID, CCL, Flag FROM TableA'));
```

You'll find a test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a830dce268f9f71780c6a5414b3fe189)*

Comment: Side note.  If you're using Oracle 12c then have a look at [this article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/implicit-statement-results-12cr1).  They added some functionality to the `DBMS_SQL` package in 12c to facilitate migrations to Oracle.  I couldn't find an online tester for Oracle 12c, so can't verify.  But I think you can just run a dynamic PIVOT with that without going via a temporary table.

Comment: you can do that with any client application which can fetch ref cursor and without creating any objects as shown in the end of my answer. That is possible starting with Oracle 7 which was released in 1992 which is 26 years ago. Implicit Results have nothing to do with dynamic SQL, just in case.

Answer (score 3):

**Oracle must know all the column in select list on PARSING stage.**

This has a couple of consequences

1. It's not possible for Oracle to change the column list of the query without re-parsing it. Regardless what is supposed to impact that - whether it's distinct list of values in some column or something else. In other words you cannot expect Oracle to add new columns to output if you added new value to CCL column in your example.
2. In each and every query you must specify explicitly all the columns in select list unless you use `"*"` with table alias. If you use `"*"` then Oracle gets column list from metadata and if you modify metadata (i.e. run DDL on a table) then Oracle re-parses query.

So the best option to deal with "Dynamic Pivoting" is to pivot and format result in the UI. However, there are still some options in database which you may want to consider.

**Generating XML with pivoted result and parsing it.**

Do pivot for XML and then parse results. In this case, eventually, you have to specify pivoted columns one way or another.

```
create table tablea(id, ccl, flag) as
(
  select 1, 'john', 'x' from dual
  union all select 1, 'adam', 'x' from dual
  union all select 1, 'terry', null from dual
  union all select 1, 'rob', 'x' from dual
  union all select 2, 'john', 'x' from dual
);
```

In below example you do NOT have to provide list of the values for CCL, the only literals you specify are:
pivoted expression (FLAG) and column used for pivoting (CCL).

```
SQL> select id, x.*
  2  from tablea t
  3  pivot xml (max(flag) flag for ccl in(any))
  4  -- parsing output
  5  , xmltable('/PivotSet' passing ccl_xml
  6             columns
  7               name1 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[1]/column[@name="CCL"]/text()',
  8               value1 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[1]/column[@name="FLAG"]/text()',
  9               name2 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[2]/column[@name="CCL"]/text()',
 10               value2 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[2]/column[@name="FLAG"]/text()',
 11               name3 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[3]/column[@name="CCL"]/text()',
 12               value3 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[3]/column[@name="FLAG"]/text()',
 13               name4 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[4]/column[@name="CCL"]/text()',
 14               value4 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[4]/column[@name="FLAG"]/text()') x;

        ID NAME1 VALUE NAME2 VALUE NAME3 VALUE NAME4 VALUE
---------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
         1 adam  x     john  x     rob   x     terry
         2 john  x
```

You may have noticed 2 important details

- In fact, each pivoted column is represented using two columns in result - one for caption and one for value
- Names are ordered so you cannot preserver order like in your example ('john', 'adam', 'terry', 'rob'),
  moreover one column may represent different names like NAME1 represents values for 'adam' in first row and 'john' in second row.

It's possible to use only indices to get the same output.

```
select id, x.*
from tablea
pivot xml (max(flag) flag for ccl in(any))
-- parsing output
, xmltable('/PivotSet' passing ccl_xml
           columns
             name1 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[1]/column[1]',
             value1 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[1]/column[2]',
             name2 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[2]/column[1]',
             value2 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[2]/column[2]',
             name3 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[3]/column[1]',
             value3 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[3]/column[2]',
             name4 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[4]/column[1]',
             value4 varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[4]/column[2]') x;
```

But still there are two columns for each pivoted column in the output.

Below query returns exactly the same data as in your example

```
SQL> select id, x.*
  2  from tablea
  3  pivot xml (max(flag) flag for ccl in(any))
  4  -- parsing output
  5  , xmltable('/PivotSet' passing ccl_xml
  6             columns
  7               john varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[column="john"]/column[2]',
  8               adam varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[column="adam"]/column[2]',
  9               terry varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[column="terry"]/column[2]',
 10               rob varchar2(30) path '/PivotSet/item[column="rob"]/column[2]') x;

        ID JOHN  ADAM  TERRY ROB
---------- ----- ----- ----- -----
         1 x     x           x
         2 x
```

But wait... all the values for CCL are specified in the query. This is because column caption cannot depend on the data in the table. So what is the point in pivoting for XML if you could have just hardcoded all values in for clause with the same success? One of the ideas is that Oracle SQL engine transposes query result and the tool which displays output just has to properly parse XML. So you split pivoting logic into two layers. XML parsing can be done outside SQL, say, in your application.

**ODCI table interface**

There is already a link in another answer to [Anton's solution](https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/).
You can also check an example [here](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=422).
And, of course, it's explained in detail in Oracle Documentation.

**Polymorphic Table Functions**

One more advanced technology has been introduces in Oracle 18 - [Polymorphic Table Functions](https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/polymorphic-table-functions-18c).
But again, you should not expect that column list of your query will change after you added new value to CCL. It can change only after re-parsing. There is a way to force hard parse before each excution, but that is another topic.

**Dynamic SQL**

Finally, as also already pointed out in the comments, you can use good old DSQL.
First step - generate SQL statement based on the table contents. Second step - execute it.

```
SQL> var rc refcursor
SQL> declare
  2    tmp clob;
  3    sql_str clob := 'select * from tablea pivot (max(flag) for ccl in ([dynamic_list]))';
  4  begin
  5    select listagg('''' || ccl || ''' as ' || ccl, ',') within group(order by max(ccl))
  6      into tmp
  7      from tablea
  8     group by ccl;
  9    open :rc for replace(sql_str, '[dynamic_list]', tmp);
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print rc

        ID ADAM  JOHN  ROB   TERRY
---------- ----- ----- ----- -----
         1 x     x     x
         2       x
```