# How do I turn rows with duplicate values to columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I try to pivot my table but keeping additional rows (in my example eeeeee   ) Is there a way in Oracle SQL to do this?

```
select * from (
select 
    mat_table.material, attribute_table.attribute, attribute_table.value
  from 
    mat_table mat_table
    inner join 
    attribute_table on mat_table.rel= attribute_table.rel
    where 




      material = 'Material_A' 
            )


material    |attribute|  value
_____________________________________

Material_A  |aaaaaa    | 
Material_A  |bbbbbb    |       hello
Material_A  |cccccc    |       val_1
Material_A  |dddddd    |       2
Material_A  |eeeeee    |       15
Material_A  |eeeeee    |       16
Material_A  |eeeeee    |       24
```

when I use pivot under the where clause

```
    pivot (
    max(attribute) as max_value for attribute IN ( 'aaaaaa', 
                                                   'bbbbbb', 
                                                   'cccccc', 
                                                   'dddddd', 
                                                   'eeeeee'
                                      ))
```

I am getting closer to what I want but for eeeee I get only one value

```
material    |aaaaaa | bbbbbb | cccccc | dddddd | eeeeee |
__________________________________________________________
Material_A  |       | hello  | val_1  | 2      | 24     |
```

but what I want is something like

```
material    |aaaaaa | bbbbbb | cccccc | dddddd | eeeeee_1 | eeeeee_2 | eeeeee_3 |
   __________________________________________________________________________________
Material_A  |       | hello  | val_1  | 2      | 15            16    |     24
```

Comment: I edited the everything :)

Answer (score 2):

If there are always 3 values for `eeeeee` then you can do it as following

```
SQL> with mat_table (material, attribute, value) as
  2  (
  3  select 'Material_A', 'aaaaaa', null from dual
  4  union all select 'Material_A', 'bbbbbb', 'hello' from dual
  5  union all select 'Material_A', 'cccccc', 'val_1' from dual
  6  union all select 'Material_A', 'dddddd', '2' from dual
  7  union all select 'Material_A', 'eeeeee', '15' from dual
  8  union all select 'Material_A', 'eeeeee', '16' from dual
  9  union all select 'Material_A', 'eeeeee', '24' from dual
 10  )
 11  select *
 12    from (select t.*,
 13                 row_number() over(partition by attribute order by value) rn
 14            from mat_table t)
 15  pivot (max(value) for (attribute, rn) in
 16  (
 17   ('aaaaaa', 1), ('bbbbbb', 1), ('cccccc', 1), ('dddddd', 1),
 18   ('eeeeee', 1), ('eeeeee', 2), ('eeeeee', 3)
 19  ));

MATERIAL   'aaaa 'bbbb 'cccc 'dddd 'eeee 'eeee 'eeee
---------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
Material_A       hello val_1 2     15    16    24
```

If, however, you expect Oracle to dynamically create columns for any number of values for `eeeeee` then that is not possible.

Please read detailed explanation here [Oracle Dynamic Pivoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259728/oracle-dynamic-pivoting/52468571#52468571)

You can generate XML for any combinations of `attribute` and `value` but if you want to display result using SQL then eventually all the columns must be specified (alternative approach is parsing XML on client side).

```
SQL> with mat_table (material, attribute, value) as
  2  (
  3  select 'Material_A', 'aaaaaa', null from dual
  4  union all select 'Material_A', 'bbbbbb', 'hello' from dual
  5  union all select 'Material_A', 'cccccc', 'val_1' from dual
  6  union all select 'Material_A', 'dddddd', '2' from dual
  7  union all select 'Material_A', 'eeeeee', '15' from dual
  8  union all select 'Material_A', 'eeeeee', '16' from dual
  9  union all select 'Material_A', 'eeeeee', '24' from dual
 10  )
 11  select material, x.*
 12  from mat_table
 13  pivot xml (count(*) as dummy for (attribute, value) in (any, any))
 14  -- parsing output
 15  , xmltable('/PivotSet' passing attribute_value_xml
 16             columns
 17               aaaaaa varchar2(10) path '/PivotSet/item[column="aaaaaa"]/column[2]',
 18               bbbbbb varchar2(10) path '/PivotSet/item[column="bbbbbb"]/column[2]',
 19               cccccc varchar2(10) path '/PivotSet/item[column="cccccc"]/column[2]',
 20               dddddd varchar2(10) path '/PivotSet/item[column="dddddd"]/column[2]',
 21               eeeeee_1 varchar2(10) path '/PivotSet/item[column="eeeeee"][1]/column[2]',
 22               eeeeee_2 varchar2(10) path '/PivotSet/item[column="eeeeee"][2]/column[2]',
 23               eeeeee_3 varchar2(10) path '/PivotSet/item[column="eeeeee"][3]/column[2]') x;

MATERIAL   AAAAAA     BBBBBB     CCCCCC     DDDDDD     EEEEEE_1   EEEEEE_2   EEEEEE_3
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Material_A            hello      val_1      2          15         16         24
```

**In this case there is no guarantee that EEEEEE_1/EEEEEE_2/EEEEEE_3 will be 15/16/24 in exactly this order.**

Comment: I have always a maximum of 3 values. I tried your code but I have EEEEEE_1: 24 and EEEEEE_2: null and EEEEEE_3 null

Comment: As you can see in the answer, code returns exactly what is required according to starting post. If you are getting something else then you either modified the code or used data with some specifics which is not taken into account. Why do not you update original post and provide an extended example?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: TS commented that it did not work for multiple materials. So I expanded the answer to account for that.

You could simply concat a row_number (partioned by material, attribute) to the attribute in your first query. You can add ordening by value if you like. To account for multiple materials the row_number to also partitioned by material. This means that the same attributes for different materials will get the same name and will end up in the same column.

replace `attribute_table.attribute` with

`concat(attribute_table.attribute,'_', row_number() over (partition by attribute_table.material, attribute_table.attribute order by attribute_table.attribute, attribute_table.value))`

Complete code and result:

```
with mat_table  as
  (
  select 'Material_A' as material, 'aaaaaa' as attribute, null as value
  union all select 'Material_A', 'bbbbbb', 'hello' 
  union all select 'Material_A', 'cccccc', 'val_1' 
  union all select 'Material_A', 'dddddd', '2' 
  union all select 'Material_A', 'eeeeee', '15' 
  union all select 'Material_A', 'eeeeee', '16' 
  union all select 'Material_A', 'eeeeee', '24' 
  union all select 'Material_B' , 'aaaaaa', 'lol' 
  union all select 'Material_B', 'bbbbbb', 'hi' 
  union all select 'Material_B', 'cccccc', 'max_val' 
  union all select 'Material_B', 'dddddd', '4' 
  union all select 'Material_B', 'eeeeee', '67' 
  union all select 'Material_B', 'eeeeee', '99' 
  union all select 'Material_B', 'eeeeee', null
  )

select *
from (
    select t.material,
            t.value ,
            concat(t.attribute,'_', row_number() over (partition by t.material , t.attribute order by t.attribute, t.value)) as numbered_attribute
    from mat_table t) as d
pivot (
    max(d.value)  
    for numbered_attribute IN ( [aaaaaa_1],  
                                [bbbbbb_1], 
                                [cccccc_1], 
                                [dddddd_1], 
                                [eeeeee_1],
                                [eeeeee_2],
                                [eeeeee_3]
                             )) as total
    order by total.material
```

Note: I used SQL-Server. Maybe you'll have to change some syntax like [eeeeee_3] => 'eeeeee_3'

Base table with numbered attributes:

[image: base table]

Final result after pivot:

[image: final result]

Comment: The actual problem is exactly the pivot process, not the column naming process.

Comment: The code he has does what he wants, except for rows with equal attribute. This solves that part of his problem.

Comment: It may not be the technically cleanest, but it's easy to understand and only needs a very small change to his current code.

Comment: Thank you it works for my example above, but not if I have more than one material. If I have a some 100 rows I will end up with as many columns :/

Comment: Updated answer to account for different materials