# Convert Row to Column in SQL query (oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have no idea to write the report to show the result as below, please assist .Much appreciated.

[image]

This is how my DB table look like

[image]

This is what I want to show in my report.

Note: the remark1,2,3 are not fixed. Sometimes will have Remark 4, Remark 5 and etc...

Comment: That's called a pivot query. Google "oracle pivot" and have a go, let us know if you hit any problems

Comment: @CaiusJard thats what I thought at first but is not possible with pivot either

Comment: The best solution I can think of is a comma separated list of remark in one column using LISTAGG

Comment: Use cross tab query using case expression

Comment: "it is not possible with pivot either"...how do you know? What did you try? What went wrong? Show us your attempt. It's a simple example and looks like it ought to be possible.

Comment: How is this not a pivot?

Comment: Guys with pivot you can aggregate based on value of column remark. You cant have Remark 1, Remark 2 etc

Comment: @CaiusJard Cant go for pivot query since the remark can more than 3 or more than 5 like Remark 4, Remark 5 and etc.

Comment: @CKAng you showed 3 rows, and said you wanted 4 columns

Comment: Please read the thread I marked as duplicated. As well as the accepted answer there is a lot of value in [Dr Y Wit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52468571/146325)

Answer (score 1):

How to pivot/transpose/crosstab data on any db(that supports analytics) using standard sql syntax, though I'm also presuming your remark can be any text at all:

```
SELECT 
  invoiceno,
  MAX(case when rn = 1 then remark end) as remark1,
  MAX(case when rn = 2 then remark end) as remark2,
  MAX(case when rn = 3 then remark end) as remark3/*,

    --add as many lines as you need columns
    MAX(case when rn = X  then remark end) as remarkX
  */
FROM
  (SELECT invoiceno, remark, row_number() over(partition by invoiceno order by remark) rn FROM table) t
GROUP BY invoiceno
```

Comment: so what happens on the 4th remark?

Comment: agree with Ted, the remark1,2,3 are not fixed. Sometimes will have Remark 4, Remark 5 and etc...

Comment: @TedatORCL.Pro you add another column?! It's fairly easy: highlight any one of the MAX lines, press ctrl-c, press ctrl-v, change the number from 3 (or whatever) to 4, 5.. If you have a thousand remarks, you have a thousand columns

Comment: @CKAng - for future reference please include pertinent details, such as variability in data, in your question. It stops people wasting their time writing answers which won't work for your actual problem.

Comment: @CKAng Basic database theory: "the number of columns is fixed, the number of rows is variable". You will run into problems every time you violate this (i.e. it's a bad idea to do so; if you have a presentational requirement do it in the front end, not the db). Or use a db that doesn't have this "number of columns is fixed" as an intrinsic design priciple