# Pivot rows into unknown number of columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have an access to Oracle server. There is a table on the Oracle server called Transactions which contains the following data:

[image]

I don't known the number of values, so we need to implement dynamic sql in Oracle.
I need to pivot that data so the results are:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Dynamic pivot in oracle sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql), [Oracle Dynamic Pivoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259728/oracle-dynamic-pivoting)

Comment: Don't do it in SQL, do it inside your application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select subno,
       sum(case when offer = 'offer1' then 1 else 0 end) as offer1,
       sum(case when offer = 'offer2' then 1 else 0 end) as offer2,
       sum(case when offer = 'offer3' then 1 else 0 end) as offer3
from t
group by subno;
```

Comment: actually, i have more than 1000 offers. so, i would need to add that number of rows for the different cases. Can we handle this?

Comment: @Taie . . . Yes and no.  Oracle has a limit on the number of columns that can be returned by a query, so you probably can't do this in Oracle.