# How to Pivot this table on Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

Can you help me figure out how to pivot this table:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦══════╦════════╦════════╗
║ Big Group ║ Small Group ║ Kids ║ Adults ║ Elders ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬════════╬════════╣
║         1 ║           1 ║   10 ║     20 ║      5 ║
║         1 ║           2 ║   15 ║     10 ║     10 ║
║         2 ║           1 ║   20 ║      0 ║     15 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩══════╩════════╩════════╝
```

Into something like this?

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦══════╦════════╦════════╦═════════════╦══════╦════════╦════════╗
║ Big Group ║ Small Group ║ Kids ║ Adults ║ Elders ║ Small Group ║ Kids ║ Adults ║ Elders ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬══════╬════════╬════════╬═════════════╬══════╬════════╬════════╣
║         1 ║           1 ║   10 ║     20 ║      5 ║           2 ║   15 ║     10 ║     10 ║
║         2 ║           1 ║   20 ║      0 ║     15 ║             ║      ║        ║        ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩══════╩════════╩════════╩═════════════╩══════╩════════╩════════╝
```

The number of small groups per Big group is variable, and that's what is being difficult for me to understand how to do it.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259728/oracle-dynamic-pivoting

Answer (score 0):

There is a way but the overhead of using `PIVOT` is to provide the list of all values which needs to be pivoted.

As you also need each small group to be pivoted we need to create a virtual column between big group and small group to be used in pivot clause as you see below

```
with table1
as
(select 1 bg
       ,1 sg,10 kids
       ,20 adult 
   from dual
 union all
 select 1,2,15,25 from dual
 union all
 select 2,1,20,0 from dual
)
select *
from 
(
select t1.*,t1.bg||'_'||t1.sg piv
  from table1 t1
)
pivot
(
max(sg) sg,max(kids) kids,max(adult) adult
for piv in ('1_1' as bg1_sg1
           ,'1_2' as bg2_sg2
           ,'2_1' as bg2_sg1)
)
order by bg
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=917047a43fa2fa28e5d4c557929c72f8)

Comment: First of all thank you for your time and answer. Unfortunately I don't think it works for what I was looking for, because if I add another big group, the extra line will be empty. I think your query only works if you know how many groups there will be, and I needed a dynamic one

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. when you say `The number of small groups per Big group is variable, and that's what is being difficult for me to understand how to do it` it doesn't mean you need dynamic (would suggest edit your title accordingly)and yes you are right when we use pivot within SQL you have to hard code the values you need to pivot. You can use of course XML for that if you know how. Finally if we have the base query , it is for sure you can create a PL/SQL block to make it dynamic but if you are looking within SQL `xml` is the only option. Choice is yours and hope you find a way out.

Comment: Continued.... @Pedro Álvaro Chagas , I would sincerely advice next time when you ask a question also try to put the code which you have already tried which make life of others like me easy to think and answer.