# Pivot with Dynamic Columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I am new oracle database I have a table like below

```
ID     Passengers Age Eligible
123456 Ben        65  Yes
123456 Mary       58  Yes
123458 Stephanie  37  Yes
123458 Aaron      32  Yes
123458 Caroline   18  No
```

I want to get the result with dynamic column name as Age1,Age2,Age3 etc.. as below

```
ID      Age1 Age2 Age3
123456  65   58   NULL
123458  37   32   18
```

It can be achieved with STUFF and Dynamic Pivot in `SQL Server` but I am not aware how to achieve this in `Oracle`

Can anyone please guide me how to do it dynamically in `Oracle`

Comment: There are many examples in SO and one of them having multiple ways is  https://stackoverflow.com/a/31420487/13878023.. Did you check and stuck somewhere ? Another simple one which also you can follow...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50259728/oracle-dynamic-pivoting

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I had gone through the questions you had mentioned here in both the dynamic column name is got from the Column Value, but I want the Same Column name Split as three Eg. Age as Age1,Age2,Age3 it is a difficult for me to doing this in Oracle as I am new to Oracle. Also I want the result set as a table

Comment: I understood and this is no problem. One question is why  `Passengers` is missing from the result ?Due to time constraint I can provide only the query and but then it can be converted it to PLSQL. or just wait and I am sure you will get a solution soon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SYS_REFCURSOR` within a stored function(*eg. PL/SQL used instead of using SQL directly*) might be used in order to get dynamically generated result set(eg. *Dynamic Pivot*). In this case, a string for Conditional Aggregation is generated :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_passengers_rs RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_str       VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG('MAX(CASE WHEN rn = '||lvl||' THEN age||''(''||passengers||'')'' END) 
                   AS "Age'||lvl||'"' ,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 0)
    INTO v_str
    FROM ( SELECT level AS lvl  
             FROM dual
          CONNECT BY level <= (SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) FROM t GROUP BY ID ) ) t;  

  v_sql :=
  'SELECT ID, '|| v_str ||'
     FROM 
     (
      SELECT t.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 0) AS rn
        FROM t     
      )
    GROUP BY ID';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
```

I also added the names of passengers in order to distinguish each data well.

Then run the below code :

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := get_passengers_rs;
PRINT rc
```

from SQL Developer's Command Line in order to see the expected result set.

Above code generates this SQL string(*v_sql*) for the currently existing data

```
SELECT ID, MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN age||'('||passengers||')' END) AS "Age1",
           MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN age||'('||passengers||')' END) AS "Age2",
           MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN age||'('||passengers||')' END) AS "Age3"
  FROM 
     (
      SELECT t.*, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 0) AS rn
        FROM t     
      )
 GROUP BY ID
```

which yields

```
ID      Age1        Age2            Age3
123456  58(Marie)   65(Ben) 
123458  32(Aaron)   18(Caroline)    37(Stephanie)
```

as result set.